# How do I wait for a file to be written or deleted on Matlab?

Tags: matlab, file

**Problem**

I am running a Matlab script that creates a mesh geometry stored within a ‘.m’ file; all of this is for running with a finite element solver. I give it a number of elements, and it creates a mesh of quadrilaterals that fit within a boundary; two examples of the geometry are shown in Figure 1 and Figure 2. When I use it for only a single number of elements, it works great. On the other hand, when I try to use the mesh-generating script within a loop, varying the number of desired elements (n = 1,2,4,...32,64), the file reads as though I just ran it at n = 1. It’s as if the ‘.m’ file was not rewritten.

[image: Mesh with 10 elements]
Figure 1. Mesh with 10 quadrilateral elements.

[image: Mesh with 40 elements]
Figure 2. Mesh with 40 quadrilateral elements.

**Current Approach**

```
for i = 1:4
    n = 2^i % n stores the desired number of elements (2^i is only an example)
    % Check if '.m' file exists in current directory
    allFiles = dir(currentFolder)
    allNames = {allFiles.name}
    check = ismember('p4.m',allNames);
    % If so, delete the file
    if check
        delete 'p4.m'
    end
    % Create the 'p4.m' file
    p4Mesh(n)
end
```

**p4Mesh Function Summary:**

```
function p4Mesh
close all; 
inputfile = 'p4.m'; 
% open file 
fid = fopen(inputfile,'w'); 
fprintf(fid,'MESH CODE HERE') 
% Close file
[st] = fclose('all'); 
end
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to delete the file at each iteration ?

Comment: @G.J I don't really have to delete them. I just wanted to see if that would help. It doesn't...

Comment: how do you write the .m file in P4Mesh function

Comment: **Here's a summary:**

   close all;
   inputfile = 'p4.m';
   % open file
   fid = fopen(inputfile,'w');
   fprintf('MESH CODE HERE')
   [st] = fclose('all');

@mhmsa

Comment: what are you expecting to be written in `'p4.m'`? you are not using the file handle at all in `p4mesh`??

Comment: I have no idea whatwould actually suggest another approach here. You know that `save` can be used to save a set of variables to .m file right? So I suggest that you use save instead if possible. Then I cannot see where you write to the file. If the code behaves as if you run it with `n=1` always it could be caused by the way you write to file or the way you calculate the mesh. Third, do not use the `dir` - `ismember` approach for finding a file. There are better ways to do this. Use instead `if exist(fileName,'file'), delete(fileName); end` . Where `'file'` is a type specifier.

Comment: @DannyG. I would actually also recommend that you have the filename as an input to `p4Mesh`. This makes the code more maintainble. There is a pain to have to go through all file every time a change is done. You would want to as much settings as possible in 1 file and if you must do changes in multiple files, you still would like to do the same change only once `fileName =  'p4.m'; if exist(fileName,'file'), delete(fileName); end, p4Mesh(n,fileName)` and define the function `p4Mesh` as `function p4Mesh(n,inputfile)`

Comment: @Shai The code looks more like the fixed version up there with fprintf(fid, 'MESH CODE HERE'). Thanks for pointing out that typo.

I know what mesh file writes; I already get working outputs when I run it with different different number of elements, but it doesn't run well in a loop because the writing system is lagging (I'm guessing), compared to the Matlab loop.

Comment: @patrik Good point. To be honest, the mesh generating functions are sometimes sent to us by our professor. He uses this standard format during his midterms, so I just prepare my code for his mesh creators.

Comment: @patrik I would use the save feature, but that saves to a '.mat' file, not a '.m' file. Also, the fprintf method is used by my professor as a standard; it would be impractical to change all of his code each time he gives us a different geometry. When I said that it runs as if I only ran n = 1, I mean that the writing feature does not work well in a loop. When I run the mesh builder separately with n = 1 and then n = 10 or some other number, it works really well. It seems that when I run it within  loop, the file writer goes to slowly. I want to match the file writer's speed to avoid errors.

Comment: Well I would suggest adding a sleep command, after p4mesh, to make sure that the file is re-written correctly

Comment: How do you know the contents of p4.m are the same each pass? And how and when are you using it? By calling it as a function? Inside the loop or after everything is done?

Comment: @AndrewJanke I see that the file is not being updated because I call the written function within the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Summary

The `p4` function definition might be getting cached so you're not picking up the new versions you write out to disk on subsequent calls to `p4()`. Use `clear p4` to drop the cached definition and force it to re-read `p4.m` each time you update it.

#### Details

You may be running in to an issue with Matlab's function definition caching. When you call a function or class for the first time, Matlab reads the definition in from the `.m` file on disk, compiles it, and runs it, and then keeps that compiled definition cached. It's pretty unlikely that the file writing is lagging the Matlab loop, since fopen/fprintf/fclose are synchronous, and Matlab is single-threaded. But Matlab's function-loading mechanism might not be noticing the changes on disk as fast as you need.

Matlab will re-read the function definition if it notices the definition has been changed on disk. If you save a function file from the Matlab Editor, it notices the change right away since that goes through Matlab. But if you write the file's contents from code, it looks to Matlab like an external change. Matlab gets updates about these changes in a system-dependent manner, like getting file change notification events from the operating system, or periodically polling the filesystem to check file timestamps. See `doc changeNotification` and `doc changeNotificationAdvanced` for details on this.

Since you're re-writing the file in a tight loop, the updates might be happening too fast for Matlab's change notification to notice. In fact, Matlab may delay the file update checks until it's done running user functions (for performance and consistency reasons), so might not do the update checks at all until it's done with your loop and returned from that script to the command line. In this case, if you called `p4()` multiple times inside the loop, it would use the cached function definition from the first pass each time, and you'd see the same output from the function. This sounds like what you're describing.

#### Diagnosis

To see if this is what is actually happening, examine the contents of the `p4.m` file on disk outside the mechanism of calling it as a Matlab function. You can use the `md5sum` program available on many systems to output a one line checksum of it. Or you can call out to `cat` or just re-read it using fopen/fread/fclose and print it or an md5 checksum of it to the console from within Matlab. If the file looks different on disk each pass, but you're getting the same output from calling `p4()`, it's probably function caching.

#### Fixing

You can force Matlab to re-read a function from the current `.m` file on disk by using the `clear` command to drop its cached compiled definition from memory. In this case, do a `clear p4;` in each pass of the loop right after you've called `p4mesh` to write out the `p4.m` file, and before `p4` gets called again.

Doing `pause` or `drawnow` inside the loop may also give Matlab's function-caching mechanism a chance to notice the updated `.m` file on disk. But `clear p4` should be more reliable and deterministic, since it forces a re-read each time.

In the long run, it might be better if you could get your professor to give you a `p4mesh` that produced `.mat` data files instead of `.m` function definition files, like the commenters suggested. The `.mat` data files are more suited to rapidly changing definitions, and don't have this caching issue.

Comment: Clearing the cache with the 'clear p4.m' command worked wonders. I appreciate your time invested in helping out.

Comment: Excellent. Do you mind Accepting the answer if this took care of your problem?